# Excel VBA AdvancedFilter via a UserForm Problems

Tags: excel, vba, userform, autofilter

I'm using Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2016. I have a table (ListObject) which is a Sharepoint linked table and a custom UserForm which has 4 comboboxes within it (Region, Country, IMType and LOB).

The logic I'm trying to apply is that the userform presents itself to the user, in the background it "unfilters" the list.  The end user can then select criteria within the userform, upon clicking OK, it inputs the values of the comboboxes, in to the 'criteria' part of the sheet and then performs an advanced filter.  Picture example below

[image: UserForm i'm using]

The following is a screen shot of the sheet i'm trying to filter

:[image: ListObject example]

admittedly, having tried ALOT of different ways to carve this turkey, I've got lost with the various different codes i've written to get around this, some of which i've pasted below but would really welcome a shining knight in meterphorical armour to steer me away from insanity here. I currently have two issues:

1)  I get an "Object Variable or With block variable not set" message and the form initiatlizes with this bit of code.  Any reason why?

```
With FilterForm
.StartUpPosition = 0
.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
.Show
End With
```

Post Form Initialization and after clicking "OK" on the userform, the following code runs:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MIMSPData")

Call AutoFilterCheck

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AJ7").Value = ""
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AK7").Value = ""
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AL7").Value = ""
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AM7").Value = ""

'    Range("'MIM Policy Governance Tracking'!MIMSPData").AdvancedFilter _
'        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("AI6:BK7"), Unique:=False
Call AdvancedFilteronSPData

Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AJ7").Value = ComboBox1.Value
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AK7").Value = ComboBox2.Value
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AL7").Value = ComboBox3.Value
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AM7").Value = ComboBox4.Value

'    Range("'MIM Policy Governance Tracking'!MIMSPData").AdvancedFilter _
'        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("AI6:BK7"), Unique:=False
Call AdvancedFilteronSPData

Unload Me
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The VB code it references (AutoFilterCheck and AdvancedFilteronSPData) are pasted below and were a late attempt for me to get around the fact the autofilter code just doesn't seem to wank to work.  They are pasted below for reference:

```
Sub AutoFilterCheck()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MIMSPData")

With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("MIMSPData").AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub
```

And the last one

```
Sub AdvancedFilteronSPData()
Dim myTable As ListObject
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MIMSPData")

    Range("MIMSPData").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("AI6:BK7"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

In short, I wondered if you could please review what i'm trying to do (ie perform an advanced filter on my listobject table based on the comboboxes criteria, and advise where i'm missing a trick as I've been at this for 2 days and seem to be going around in circles.

Your help would be much appreciated, Merry Christmas all.

Comment: For the first error you just have to put the filterform.show code in another part where you will just show the userform !

Comment: Update: So I recorded the steps to perform an Advanced Filter manually (Data > Advanced) and I noticed in the code, it's referencing my List Object as 'External Data', see below.  I wondered if this has something to do with my issue?

Comment: Thanks Imran, I'll put it in a module and call it.  Good advice :)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to play around with the code and since doing so, I@ve been able to fix the issue I was experiencing so wanted to post my updated code here.  Thanks to Imran for his comment about the UserForm error I had.

The difference seemed to be how I referenced the Table object (instead of accepting Excel's default 'recorded' version (which was

```
Range("'MIM Policy Governance Tracking'!MIMSPData").AdvancedFilter
```

I changed it to:

```
Range("MIMSPData[#All]").AdvancedFilter
```

This seems to have resolved my issue.  If however, anyone out there can spot a better way of doing this, I'd be open to suggestions.  I'm only a part-time dabbler in VBA so would welcome a guru's input here.  Hope this can help others.

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

'Clear existing entries cell values
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AJ7").Value = ""
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AK7").Value = ""
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AL7").Value = ""
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AM7").Value = ""

'Filter to show all
Range("MIMSPData[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("AJ6:AM7"), Unique:=False

'Input new cell values based on current criteria
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AJ7").Value = ComboBox1.Value
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AK7").Value = ComboBox2.Value
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AL7").Value = ComboBox3.Value
Sheets("MIM Policy Governance Tracking").Range("AM7").Value = ComboBox4.Value

'Filter to show updated results
Range("MIMSPData[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("AJ6:AM7"), Unique:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Unload Me
End Sub
```